# TTS is attached to app automatically when accessibility service and admob ads where used

Tags: android, admob, accessibility, text-to-speech

I am facing a strange issue when I uses adMob ads with accessibility service enabled.

Once ads where received TTS engine is automatically attached to my app and showing the TTS process as in use under Settings -> Apps -> running process. There is no logic related to TTS in my app but still TTS is being attached to my app process and not releasing it.

** Note: I have tried creating a very simple app which uses only accessibility service and admob ads which confirmed this issue.

Below is the code for accessibility service:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.accessibilitytestxml.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.accessibilitytestxml.TestAccessibilityService"
        android:label="Test Accessibility XML App"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" /-->
    </service>

     <!-- AdMob Code Start -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <!-- AdMob Code End -->
</application>
```

**MyAccessibilityService.java**

```
public class TestAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
...
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

      System.out.println("My event: "+event.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    info.packageNames = null;

     setServiceInfo(info);
    }    
...
}
```

Below is the simple code for Showing Ads:

**MainActivity.java**

```
final AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxx"); 
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AdLinearLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Please find the console log:

```
09-19 22:00:46.763: I/Ads(26011): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/......... type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
09-19 22:00:46.763: I/Ads(26011): Request scenario: Online server request.
09-19 22:00:47.413: D/dalvikvm(26011): GC_CONCURRENT freed 233K, 5% free 9392K/9863K, paused 1ms+7ms
09-19 22:00:47.873: D/webviewglue(26011): nativeDestroy view: 0x1b5e98
09-19 22:00:47.903: I/TextToSpeech(26011): Sucessfully bound to com.svox.classic
09-19 22:00:47.903: I/Ads(26011): onReceiveAd()
09-19 22:00:47.943: D/dalvikvm(26011): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 206K, 7% free 9205K/9863K, paused 34ms
09-19 22:00:48.123: I/TextToSpeech(26011): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.classic/com.svox.classic.SvoxTtsService}
```

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView has its own JavaScript-based screen reader and connects to TTS directly when an accessibility service is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is.

You have declared an AccessibilityService with an IntentFilter of android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService. So it is not surprising that it is receiving accessibility notifications.

Comment: I am not receiving any accessibility event for TTS bound/connected status because of the eventTypes I have given and that is working as expected. You can see the console log which says the TTS status was printed from TTS engine and it is not from accessibility service method.  
* Here my problem is TTS engine get bound to my app when I receive an ad response which is not intended action. Infact I am not using any TTS related code in my app. I know it is sound strange but this is happening.

Comment: The ad WebView may well be posting an accessibility event which would be picked up by your IntentFilter. This is why the log is the way it is. I still do not understand why you think it is a problem.

Comment: Thanks it make sense, once TTS is attached to my app it occupying extra 11mb of my app memory for TTS engine and it did not releases.